# How to run the ci on windows, linux and macos?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm trying to package a Python and Qt app with pyinstaller. I, however, haven't found a way to run multiple runners in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically would duplicate the job definition and just assign different [tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags) to pick the runners you want. Here's how I build an Electron app on three different runners in parallel:

```yaml
.build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install --progress=false
    - npm run electron:build

build-linux:
  extends: .build
  tags:
    - linux

build-mac:
  extends: .build
  tags:
    - mac

build-windows:
  extends: .build
  tags:
    - windows
```

This config makes use of [hidden jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#hide-jobs) and [extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends).

Answer (score 1):

Since GitLab 14.1 it's possible to use the [`parallel: matrix:` keyword in combination with `tags`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#select-different-runner-tags-for-each-parallel-matrix-job), e.g.

```
build:
  script:
  - npm install --progress=false
  - npm run electron:build
  parallel:
    matrix:
    - PLATFORM: [linux, macos, windows]
  tags:
  - ${PLATFORM}
```

The `tags:` keyword should then pick up the CI runner for the specified operating system.